# EU airlines, late for connection flight due to lines on passport control

Tags: short-connections, compensation, missed-flights

Several days ago I had 1 hour connection in Amsterdam and I got my plane but I was the last one, after me they closed the gate.

Now I need to buy a new ticket and thinking about the same route. Is airline obliged to pay 250€ compenstion in case of missing connection due to very long queues on passport control, slow security check, delay in a bus form previous flight?

I my case I should arrive at 16 00, but I arrived in 16 10, 10 minutes in a bus, after it 10 minutes running between gates, 10 minutes for security check and 30 minutes on passport control. All of this was quite extremely.

So in case of late in such situation will airline pay a compensation if next flight depart in more than 3 hours?

Comment: I suspect the airline will claim that those are circumstances beyond its control and deny compensation.

Comment: OK, but will they in this case rebook my flight? Or they'll cancel my ticket at all? :)

Comment: If it's on one ticket, they will rebook you without charge.

Comment: At least this one is good :)

Comment: Very important, were both flights booked on the same itinerary?

Comment: Yes, all flights were bought in one ticket, all was done by KLM

Comment: Note that airlines often offer 'fast-tracking' you if they are aware of the problem. Make sure to inform the personnel on the incoming flight (early enough) that you have that tight connection. Chances are they set up someone to meet you (and other people from your plane) at the plane door who will drive you or guide you through 'back ways' to your departure gate, bypassing lines and getting you directly to the front of any mandatory queues. Thatˋs not a guarantee, but I have seen it very often.

Comment: Another method you can use if the airline offers no assistance and your flight's departure is imminent: push your way (as politely as possible, but firmly) to the front of the line. I'd try to find some kind of official to direct you first though.

Comment: Yes, KLM offered me "fast track", that's why I was only 30 minutes on passport control. Without it it would be an hour, maybe more.
One time in a very short connection Swiss met me near the plane and drived to another plane by car, unfortunately KLM did not offer something like this

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, there are few things to take into consideration :

- if you have a single booking reference for all the itinerary, then the airline considered that you could make it as they have allowed this booking and so you'll be booked on a later flight if for some reasons you aren't able to make it
- if you have two separate bookings, then it will most of the time be your problem unless you can find an agreement with the airline but if you missed it for 10 minutes delay, it won't be enough to justify a free rebook on a later flight with most companies
- as mentioned in one of the comments, you should let the airline crew know about your situation. They'll call some staff on the ground to escort you and make the connection happen.
- I doubt that you'll get a monetary compensation for being delayed in this situation. If the flight had 10 minutes delay, it isn't enough to entitle you for a compensation, even if this generates further delay because of missed leg. The only thing you'll eventually get is vouchers to drink something or a hotel night if the rebooked flight is the day after. The monetary compensation is usually related to flight delay, not to missed flight (ie when you aren't able to take the flight).

Comment: I have received EU261 compensation following a short delay that caused me to miss a connection and be delayed by 12 hours. The key is the cause of the delay rather than the time period

Comment: I agree with you that the cause is important. Still some companies will be more flexible to offer compensations than others... :)

Comment: The one time I was met on arrival of a late flight, to be brought to the next, I nearly missed the flight because of that. I was one of the first of the plane but they waited till every body was off before starting walking. Then we had to join the normal queues for passport control and security. The only thing they did was point the way, which was well signposted. I made the flight but had no time to put things back in the bag after security.